# How are pointers "variables whose values are an address" when we can do char *string = "string"?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I've always understood pointers as follows:

```
int x = 5;
int *y = &x;

printf("%d", *y);
```

- I store 5 at some memory location and allow myself to access that value with `x`.
- I create an integer pointer `y`, setting its memory location to the memory location of `x`.
- I print the value stored at the address that `y` holds.

However, I can at the same time do `char *string = "neato"` and it's totally functional. To me this looks like "create a character pointer, holding the memory address 'neato'". How does that make any sense?

Furthermore, if I set it, I would try to do it as `*string = "more neat"` but that gives an error. I instead need to do `string = "more neat"`. The first attempt intuitively looks like "change the value stored at the memory address held by string to 'more neat'", but it doesn't work. The second looks to me like "for the memory address held by 'string', change it to 'more neato'. And that totally doesn't make sense to me.

What am I confusing? If in order to access the value stored at a pointer I need to do `printf("%d", *pointer)`, how is *setting* its value not along those lines as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unary `*` operator has two different (but related) purposes. In a *declaration*, it denotes that the type is a pointer type, but does not imply that the pointer is being dereferenced.

When used in an *expression*, it denotes deferencing the pointer.  That's why your example works where it's a declaration, but when you dereference it you can't assign (because the appropriate type to assign would be a char, if you could modify string literals anyhow).

The equivalent way to do it outside the declaration looks like:

```
const char *s = "hello"; /* initialize pointer value */
s = "goodbye"; /* assign to pointer value */
```

The above initialization and assignment are equivalent.

Comment: Why are they? Its const and afaik not mutable. Sorry but i speak more in c# then in c. Perhaps this is possible in c?

Comment: What do you mean by "(because the appropriate type to assign would be a char, if you could modify string literals anyhow)" I'm just confused that with the example I gave, if I wanted to change `x` through `y`, I'd go `*y = 10;`. But if I want to change a `char` pointer I don't use the asterisk? When I do `*string = "new string" what exactly is occurring? Does it dereference `string` and give me the "n" as it's first in the array, and then I try to set "n" to "new string" which fails? What does `string = "new string"` do then? Does it set `"new string"` into the corresponding array indices?

Comment: @icbytes, you are mixing up to which object the `const` applies, here.  `const char*` or equivalently `char const*` has the object that is pointed to `const` not the pointer itself. That would be `char*const`, a pointer that can't be change but the object can, or `char const*const`, none can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

`"neato"` is of the type `const char[]`.  Arrays decay to pointers when appropriate, so the assignment is one pointer to another.

It follows then that your pointer should be to `const char`.  Writing to a memory location occupied by a string literal invokes undefined behavior.  This however is valid:

```
char str[] = "neato";
str[0] = 'p';
```

> Furthermore, if I set it, I would try to do it as *string = "more neat"

Well, you have a pointer to *char*, so that assignment doesn't make sense (also what I said above about writing to a string literal.)

Comment: More precisely, it should be a pointer to `const char` (`const char *string`), not *necessarily* a `const` pointer (`char *const`). Though `const char *const string` wouldn't be a bad idea if you don't intend to change either the contents of `string` (an address) or the contents of what it points to (the actual string).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yeah, I turned around my wording. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

The basic type of both `char *` and the string "neato" is a char; String literals are simply arrays of characters, often located in read-only addresses. "n" must be located in an address (as must be the next character 'e' and so on). That address is stored in the variable `char *ptr`;

The second part of the question is with why `*ptr = "more neat";` is invalid.

`*var` dereferences the address -- in this case the 1-character wide memory address, that contains already the character 'n'. You can't put either the address of the new string literal (probably representable in 4 or 8 bytes) to a single char; nor can you put the 9 characters and the terminating ascii-zero in it.

We may study this by taking a memory dump of a 16-bit (Big Endian) machine;

```
  0FFE: .. ..             // other variables, return addresses etc.
  1000: F0 00             // The pointer "var" is located here
  1002:                   // Top of stack

  F000: "n" "e" "a" "t" "o" 00      // Address of constant string is F000
  F006: "m" "o" "r" "e" ...         // Address of next string is F006
```

`*var` accesses the single byte memory at F000. `var` is itself located at address 0000 and is in this machine two bytes, because addresses are here 16-bit wide. After the new assignment `var="more neat"`; The memory dump is:

```
  1000: F0 06             // Pointer holds a new address
```

Comment: As far i know, char pointers always point to the first (0) char of  a charsequence. So the op mixes integer pointers with char pointers?

Comment: Possibly -- one has to understand that pointers are not merely addresses, but addresses associated with the type of item the address holds.

Comment: So `*var* dereferences the address, that is to get the value stored at the address, and then I try to set that value, in my case "n" (as it's the first value in the array) to "more neato", which causes it to fail (as that doesn't make sense)? What exactly is `string = "new string"` doing then? As `string` is just an address without the `*`, is it saying set that address and the ones after it to "more neato"?

Comment: @ Aki Suihkonen : That is partially true. Because the pointer itself is always integer, either 32 or 64 bit large. Thats mostly all pointer casts results are working. But correct me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
char *ptr = "neato";
char arr[] = "neato";
```

are completely different. *ptr* is a pointer to the string literal "neato" and the compiler usually stores the string literal in read-only memory. So you can't change the string literal *ptr* points to, but you can change the value of *ptr*, namely the address.

```
*ptr = "more neat"; // error, even if *ptr were writable, it should be a character
*ptr = 'b'; // error
ptr = "more neat"; // ok, you just create another string literal and ptr now points to it
```

The second one is just an abbreviation of

```
char arr[] = {'n', 'e', 'a', 't', 'o', '\0'};
```

In this case, you can change the characters in the array, but you can't change the address of arr(yeah, it's an array)

```
*arr = 'b'; // ok
arr = "more neat" // error, the value of arr, namely the address of the array cannot be changed
```

Initialisation and Assignment are different, even if they look pretty similar, the meaning of the operation is often different.

Comment: What confused me was that in your example, `ptr` is a memory address, right? If I checked its value, it would be a memory address. So when I do `ptr = "something"` it felt to me like you were setting the memory address of `ptr` (which is a number) to a string. But in reality, you're almost re-initializing another string, which would require a new memory address, and then `ptr` is updated to point at that new memory address instead?

Comment: So how does `ptr = "string"` tell the difference between me wanting to do the whole "re-initialize a string and set `ptr` to its new memory address" and `ptr = 1004` where I want to manually set its memory address. Does the compiler check what it's being set to, and in the case of a string, realize it needs a new memory address, but for other things such as an integer realize it means a change of memory address to what I specify?

Comment: string and integer are different, in that string is an "array" of characters. ptr stores just the address of the first character of the string. when compiler sees ptr = "string";, it allocates memory and store "string" there. and then assign its address to ptr.

Comment: Actually, string literal itself is just an address where the string is stored.(except for when initialising array of characters like in the example above)